# Unable to update composer.phar in yii2

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I am using the below command to update my composer:

```
php composer.phar update
```

I am getting the below error in the terminal:

```
[Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]                            
  The contents of http://packagist.org/p/provider-archived%2491683312159b2222  
  f06683bc446f1347559e31839d8dbb6a3c2512e677e01798.json do not match its sign  
  ature. This should indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running compose  
  r again and report this if you think it is a mistake.
```

I am not able to figure out the issue can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you also checked if this is happening after an `composer self-update`?

Comment: This command is returning me: Updating to version 3d9daea6a048fea7f161742dedf280223a1f2901.
    Downloading: 100%         
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version d901101286d54fe1170a729ab8330e7465f65f7c

Comment: and? is the problem now fixed after you updated composer?

Comment: No not at all not resolved. still the same error

Comment: Could you complete your `composer.json` please? Also have you tried deleting `/vendor` + `composer.lock` and retry your command?

Comment: Yes, tried. but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I added the below lines in my composer.json and everything started working.

```
 "repositories": {
        "packagist": { "url": "https://packagist.org", "type": "composer" }
    },
```

I don't know the purpose but it is working for me and I am able to run

```
php composer.phar update
```